# Cannot connect to `redis-server` running in wsl2 using `ioredis` package due to ECONNREFUSED error

Tags: node.js, redis, wsl-2, ioredis

I'm am running my `redis-server` by building `redis` in my wsl2 Ubuntu distro. But unfortunately, I'm not able to connect to it using the `ioredis` package. Here is my code (It's the same code that `ioredis` provided):-

```js
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const redis = new Redis({
  port: 6379,
  host: '127.0.0.1'
});

redis.set("foo", "bar");

redis.get("foo", function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(result); // Promise resolves to "bar"
  }
});
```

Every time I get the following error

```sh
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1146:16)
```

I am able to connect to the `redis-server` using `redis-client` from my wsl2 terminal, just not from my code. I haven't changed the default Redis configuration, so I am not sure where this is coming from. Any sort of lead would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of trying out different solutions, I was able to fix the issue. Since `redis-server` on wsl2 was running on a separate network, accessing it via `127.0.0.1` didn't work. I needed to know the IP address of my wsl2 instance and pass the correct connection details in ioredis constructor.

1. Type `sudo apt install net-tools` in your wsl2 terminal
2. Type `ifconfig` to get the IP address. It should be in the `eth0` `inet` section.
3. Copy and paste the IP address when creating the ioredis instance

```js
const redis = new Redis({
 port: 6379,
 host: '<your-wsl2-ip-here>'
});
```

4. Type `redis-cli` and then turn off protected mode using `CONFIG SET protected-mode no`.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving the above issue would be by loading the default config file `redis.conf` located in the one level above the `redis-server` executable, which has the necessary configuration to allow external traffic into the wsl2 process.

```sh
./redis-server ../redis.conf
```

Comment: what do you mean by this? i don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find your ip using this simple command where `redis-server` is your container name that you get when you run `docker ps` in the terminal:

> docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' redis-server

This should give you the same ip as the [recommended answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69448525/6141587) :)